# Is "sein" the only verb where the infinitive is different from the 3rd person plural?

Tags: verb, conjugation

Is *sein* the only verb where the infinitive is different from the 3rd person plural conjugation?  (obviously excluding separable and reflexive verbs)

Comment: Wow, they are really different! I've somehow learned it, without ever recognizing it.